# how to auto resize card view in flutter based on the content

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, cardview, flutter-widget

I am facing an issue in flutter where I have a listview inside a card widget.  I am reading data from the SQLite database to populate my listview. I don't know how long the listview will be. My problem is that currently I am setting a fixed height to cardview and since my listview can be long or short I get an overflow pixel error.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:finsec/widget/single_line_list_view.dart';
import 'package:finsec/widget/header.dart';

import 'package:finsec/data/cardview_list_item.dart';

class cardView extends StatelessWidget {
  cardView({
    this.header,
    this.elevation,
    this.padding,
    this.query,
    this.iconColor
  });

  String header, query;
  double elevation, padding;
  Color iconColor;

  final shape = const RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
        topRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
      )
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, padding, 0.0, 0.0),  //vertical padding between cardivew and $s0.00
      child: new Card(
        elevation: elevation,
        shape: shape,
        child: new Container(
          width: MediaQuery
              .of(context)
              .size
              .width,
          height: 165.00,
          child: new Column(
            children:[
              Header(text: header,
                textSize: 24.0,
                backgroundColor: Color(0xffC4C4C4),
                textColor: Colors.black,
                height: 50,
                padding: 20.0,
                headerRadius: 8.0
              ),
            CardviewListItemData(query)  //listview goes here

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If my listview returns 2 items then cardview looks ok but after 3 items or more I get an overflow pixel error.  The reason is I am setting the height of the container to 165.00 manually.
see pic below

[image]

How can I fix my code so that the cardview auto resizes based on the number of items in my listview?  For example, if my listview returns 5 items then cardview should show all five items. I cannot set the height manually because I don't know the number of items on the list. Is there any way to dynamically resize the cardview to show any number of items returned by the listview?

Answer (score 4):

You can try to surround your card within a `Row` widget within `IntrinsicHeight` widget  with crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch

With this, children of Row (your cards) will expand vertically, but Row will take the least amount of vertical space available.

```
Container(
  child: IntrinsicHeight(
    child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        YourCard(
          width: 20.0,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
)
```

Comment: thanks Anirudh but i tried your solution and doesnt work. i get the following error.   ╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY 
I/flutter ( 6170): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter ( 6170): RenderShrinkWrappingViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.
I/flutter Calculating the intrinsic dimensions would require instantiating every child of the viewport, which
I/flutter ( 6170): defeats the point of viewports being lazy.
I/flutter ( 6170): If you are merely trying to shrink-wrap the viewport in the main axis direction, you should be able

Comment: it happens when the container doesn't have a fixed size. Can you try adding some height and width to it

Comment: i added height but still errors.  can you write/code an example of listview inside a carview to show how you solve the problem and share the code with me?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the ListView is inside a Column, try to wrap your CardviewListItemData in a Flexible widget.